# Current division and power delivery to resistors

Tags: resistors, current-source, optimization

I am trying to get the resistor e in this circuit to consume the most power possible by changing its resistance. It seems 100 ohms is just about right, a little less or more and it's power consumption goes down according to the simulations.

However I am wondering if it is a coincidence that the current going along the main loop to the right is the same as the the current that is going through a when the resistor e's power consumption is at it's highest. i.e does diving current evenly through parallel circuit yield maximum power??

I would like to prove mathematically why a 100 ohm is the best choice for resistor e in terms of maximising power consumption however I am not sure where to start.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f8GrNm.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To mathematically prove, remove the resistance *e* and find the Thevnin's equivalent resistance across it. (*edit:* You have to replace the diode D1 with its equivalent circuit. Since D1 is reverse biased, you can replace it with an open circuit. )

According to [Max power transfer theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_power_transfer_theorem), the value for *e* must be equal to thevnin's resistance you calculated for maximum power transfer.

Comment: Thank you. I have been asked to actually find what values will yield maximum efficiency but it seems the system would receive no power at maximum efficiency, so I am trying to find a good middle ground